# Web component, how to get an element by Id?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I want to grab an element by its ID. My template looks like this:

```
<template>
    <h2>Welcome</h2>    
    <div id="toGrab"></div>
</template>
```

I tried using jQuery but the below snippet doesn't work:

```
$('#toGrab').dosomething();
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried just using `document.getElementById("toGrab")`?

Comment: `$('#toGrab).dosomething();` might even work, depending on what the context of the code is. Because you didn't provide any context at all, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Ha, it seems that `$(this.$.toGrab).dosomething()` do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you code is inside the Polymer element, just do

```
var div = this.$.toGrab;
```

Comment: I guess you should read the Polymer docs. There are lot's of things provider by Polymer that should be used. Your next question will probably be "Why can't I get an element with `this.$.toGrab` when the element is inside a `<template is="dom-if">`?"

Comment: Can you add a link to the polymer doc?

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/getting-the-code.html especially the "Developer guide" menu

Answer (score 3):

In Polymer 3:

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  const x = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('divID');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also...

```
var div = this.$$("#toGrab");
```